# div not showing when changing style in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to simply change the display property of a couple of elements when a link is hovered over, the elements default display in none. Here is the relevant code. I've removed the svg content as it takes up too much characters. Thankyou!

```js
class LinkContainer {
    animating = false;
    alias;
    colours;
    link;
    textelements;
    shown;

    constructor(alias, link, colours, textelements) {
        this.alias = alias
        this.colours = colours;
        this.link = link;
        textelements == null ? this.textelements = [] : this.textelements = Array.from(textelements)
        console.log(this.textelements)
        // this.textelements.forEach((element) => {
        //     element.Hide;
        // });
    }

    toggletextelements(state) {
        if (this.textelements.length == 0)
            return

        if (state) {
            // let t1 = TimelineMax();
            let transition = false;
            linkcontainers.forEach((container) => {
                // console.log(container.shown && container.alias != this.alias);
                if (container.shown && container.alias != this.alias) {
                    const tween = KUTE.fromTo(
                        `.${this.alias} svg`,
                        { path: `.${this.alias} svg` },
                        { path: `.${container.alias} svg` },
                    ).start();
                    this.shown = true;
                } else {
                    // $(this.textelements[0]).show();
                    // console.log(" ~ file: main.js ~ line 38 ~ LinkContainer ~ linkcontainers.forEach ~ textelements", $(this.textelements[0]));
                    this.textelements.forEach((textelement) => {
                        textelement.style.display = 'block';
                        //     // t1.fromTo(textelement, 0.1, {
                        //     //     opacity: "0" }, {
                        //     //     opacity: "1"
                        //     // }); 
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

linkcontainerobjects = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('link-container'));

// console.log(linkcontainerobjects);

linkcontainers = [];

linkcontainerobjects.forEach((container) => {
    colours = container.getElementsByClassName('colour');
    linkcontainers.push(
        new LinkContainer(
            container.dataset.alias,
            container.getElementsByClassName('link')[0],
            [colours[0], colours[1], colours[2], colours[3]],
            document.getElementsByClassName(container.dataset.alias)
        )
    );
});



const tl = new TimelineMax();
const speed = 0.05;
const width = '40%'

linkcontainers.forEach((container) => {
    container.link.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
        if (!container.animating) {
            container.animating = true;
            container.colours.forEach((colour) => {
                tl.fromTo(colour, speed, {
                    width: "0%"
                }, {
                    width: width,
                });
            });
        } container.animating = false;
        container.toggletextelements('block');
    });

    container.link.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) => {
        if (!container.animating) {
            container.animating = true;
            container.colours.forEach((colour) => {
                tl.fromTo(colour, speed, {
                    width: width
                }, {
                    width: "0%"
                });
            });
        } container.animating = false;
        container.toggletextelements('none');
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap');

body {
    background-color: rgb(15, 15, 15);
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    /* overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden; */
    grid-template: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.links {
    margin: 10% 0 0 5%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
    width: 40%;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.link {
    color: white;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 2;
}

.colour {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 75px;
    transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(-1px);
    z-index: 1;
}

.one {
    background-color: #00DDFF;
}

.two {
    background-color: #00FFAE;
}

.three {
    background-color: #7bff00;
}

.four {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #00e1ff, #D0FF00);
    /* width: 100%; */
}

.section {
    height: 100%;
    grid-column: 2 / 2;
    display: none;
    transform: 
    translateX(-3em)
    translateY(-4.5em);
}

.section svg {
    position: absolute;
    display: inherit;
    transform: 
    scale(120%)
    rotate(-90deg)
    translateX(-1em)
    translateY(-37em);
}

.filler {
    background-color: #0a97ff;
    position: absolute;
    display: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 152.4%;
    transform: 
    translateX(5em);
}

.section p {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    display: inherit;
    width: 20em;
    text-align: right;
    transform:
    translateX(2em)
    translateY(15em);
}

.section h {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    display: inherit;
    font-size: 5em;
    width: 29%;
    text-align: right;
    transform:
    translateX(4em)
    translateY(3em);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TimelineMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/kute.js@2.1.2/dist/kute.min.js
    "></script>

    <div class="links">
        <div class="link-container" data-alias="home" id="home">
            <div class="colour one"></div>
            <div class="colour two"></div>
            <div class="colour three"></div>
            <div class="colour four"></div>
            <a class="link" href="#">home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link-container" data-alias="projects">
            <div class="colour one"></div>
            <div class="colour two"></div>
            <div class="colour three"></div>
            <div class="colour four"></div>
            <a class="link" href="#">projects</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link-container" data-alias="about">
            <div class="colour one"></div>
            <div class="colour two"></div>
            <div class="colour three"></div>
            <div class="colour four"></div>
            <a class="link" href="#">about</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link-container" data-alias="training">
            <div class="colour one"></div>
            <div class="colour two"></div>
            <div class="colour three"></div>
            <div class="colour four"></div>
            <a class="link" href="#">training</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link-container" data-alias="experiments">
            <div class="colour one"></div>
            <div class="colour two"></div>
            <div class="colour three"></div>
            <div class="colour four"></div>
            <a class="link" href="#">experiments</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link-container" data-alias="contact">
            <div class="colour one"></div>
            <div class="colour two"></div>
            <div class="colour three"></div>
            <div class="colour four"></div>
            <a class="link" href="#">contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section">
        <div class="home">
            <svg id="visual" class="content home" 
            viewBox="0 0 900 600" width="900" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><path d="" fill="#0a97ff"></path></svg>
            <div class="filler home"></div>
            <h class="content projects" class="content home">
                Lorem
            </h class="content projects">
            <p class="content home">
                Pariatur proident commodo adipisicing cillum quis. Officia do do ipsum laborum commodo et nulla consequat
                culpa elit aute. Elit sit eiusmod qui amet amet fugiat est. Consectetur deserunt incididunt excepteur labore
                ullamco ut irure dolor. Ipsum laborum irure fugiat aute exercitation incididunt nostrud dolor proident
                laborum culpa. Deserunt Lorem ex duis ex do officia cupidatat id duis sit. Eu dolor non ad est dolore.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="projects">
            <svg class="content projects" id="visual" viewBox="0 0 900 600" width="900" height="600" class="content projects" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><path d="" fill="#0a97ff"></path></svg>
            <h class="content projects">
                Lorem
            </h>
            <p class="content projects">
                Pariatur proident commodo adipisicing cillum quis. Officia do do ipsum laborum commodo et nulla consequat
                culpa elit aute. Elit sit eiusmod qui amet amet fugiat est. Consectetur deserunt incididunt excepteur labore
                ullamco ut irure dolor. Ipsum laborum irure fugiat aute exercitation incididunt nostrud dolor proident
                laborum culpa. Deserunt Lorem ex duis ex do officia cupidatat id duis sit. Eu dolor non ad est dolore.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="about">
            <svg class="content about" id="outer" viewBox="0 0 1000 800" width="1000" height="900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="800" fill="#0f0f0f"></rect>
            <g transform="translate(534.7368600969783 383.1406775770206)">
                <path
                d=""
                fill="#00fff0"></path>
            </g>
            </svg>
            <svg class="content projects" id="visual" viewBox="0 0 900 600" width="900" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><path d="" fill="#0a97ff"></path></svg>
            <h class="content about">
                Lorem
            </h>
            <p class="content about">
                Pariatur proident commodo adipisicing cillum quis. Officia do do ipsum laborum commodo et nulla consequat
                culpa elit aute. Elit sit eiusmod qui amet amet fugiat est. Consectetur deserunt incididunt excepteur labore
                ullamco ut irure dolor. Ipsum laborum irure fugiat aute exercitation incididunt nostrud dolor proident
                laborum culpa. Deserunt Lorem ex duis ex do officia cupidatat id duis sit. Eu dolor non ad est dolore.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="training">
            <svg class="content training" id="visual" viewBox="0 0 900 600" width="900" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><path d="" fill="#0a97ff"></path></svg>
            <h class="content training">
                Lorem
            </h>
            <p class="content training">
                Pariatur proident commodo adipisicing cillum quis. Officia do do ipsum laborum commodo et nulla consequat
                culpa elit aute. Elit sit eiusmod qui amet amet fugiat est. Consectetur deserunt incididunt excepteur labore
                ullamco ut irure dolor. Ipsum laborum irure fugiat aute exercitation incididunt nostrud dolor proident
                laborum culpa. Deserunt Lorem ex duis ex do officia cupidatat id duis sit. Eu dolor non ad est dolore.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="experiments">
            <svg class="content experiments" id="visual" viewBox="0 0 900 600" width="900" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><path d="" fill="#0a97ff"></path></svg>
            <h class="content experimentsw">
                Lorem
            </h>
            <p class="content experiments">
                Pariatur proident commodo adipisicing cillum quis. Officia do do ipsum laborum commodo et nulla consequat
                culpa elit aute. Elit sit eiusmod qui amet amet fugiat est. Consectetur deserunt incididunt excepteur labore
                ullamco ut irure dolor. Ipsum laborum irure fugiat aute exercitation incididunt nostrud dolor proident
                laborum culpa. Deserunt Lorem ex duis ex do officia cupidatat id duis sit. Eu dolor non ad est dolore.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="contact">   
            <svg class="content contact" id="visual" viewBox="0 0 900 600" width="900" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><path d="" fill="#0a97ff"></path></svg>
            <h class="content contact">
                Lorem
            </h>
            <p class="content contact">
                Pariatur proident commodo adipisicing cillum quis. Officia do do ipsum laborum commodo et nulla consequat
                culpa elit aute. Elit sit eiusmod qui amet amet fugiat est. Consectetur deserunt incididunt excepteur labore
                ullamco ut irure dolor. Ipsum laborum irure fugiat aute exercitation incididunt nostrud dolor proident
                laborum culpa. Deserunt Lorem ex duis ex do officia cupidatat id duis sit. Eu dolor non ad est dolore.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is ```h``` tag? Did you mean ```h1``` for example? Also when you put just part of a ```js class function``` like **this.textelements**, it is not clear for others to understand the problem. Suppose that you yourself want to answer this question. Could you reproduce the problem by that codes in your development environment? ```link-container``` class is not mentioned in ```html code```!

Comment: Ok sure i'll attach those, the other things aren't relevent, as i've debugged it, but i'll still add it. thankyou!

Comment: @hamid-davodi I've added in all the code, thankyou so much! It's such a simple problem i'm having and i've tried for ages to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspected your codes, first of all I found some problems (in my opinion) in the `html` code. We don't have `h` tag, So I changed all of them to `h1`. Also in some cases you inserted `class` attribute twice! or in the closing tag! So I fixed all of them in my final code.

Next I inspect the **JavaScript** code. In a line you used `new TimelineMax();`. But you did not insert the code of that. So I commented the codes related to it in my final solution (maybe codes related to `animating`).

Finally the main problem comes from `toggletextelements` method in the `LinkContainer` class. In the `else` part of `if`, where you want to change the style, there are two problems:

1. **problem-1**: You did not use the `state` parameter in the code, and set "block" string instead. In that case always `display:block` applies, But you want `display:none` when `mouseleave` occurs. So I changed that.
2. **problem-2**: In your style-sheet you set `display: none;` for `.section` class that is the parent of **all `<div>` tags** that you want to apply `display:block` in your js code. that is the reason your changing style does not work. So I added `.section > div { display: none; }` to the style-sheet and changed the js code in `else` part that applies `display:block` to both `<div>s` tags and their parent (**.section class**) with the help of `closest('.section')` js method

this is my final code:

```js
class LinkContainer {
    animating = false;
    alias;
    colours;
    link;
    textelements;
    shown;

    constructor(alias, link, colours, textelements) {
        this.alias = alias
        this.colours = colours;
        this.link = link;
        textelements == null ? this.textelements = [] : this.textelements = Array.from(textelements)
        // console.log(this.textelements)
        // this.textelements.forEach((element) => {
        //     element.Hide;
        // });
    }

    toggletextelements(state) {
        // console.log("hovered");
        if (this.textelements.length == 0) {

            return;
        }


        if (state) {
            // let t1 = TimelineMax();
            let transition = false;
            linkcontainers.forEach((container) => {
                // console.log(container.shown && container.alias != this.alias);
                if (container.shown && container.alias != this.alias) {

                    const tween = KUTE.fromTo(
                        `.${this.alias} svg`,
                        { path: `.${this.alias} svg` },
                        { path: `.${container.alias} svg` },
                    ).start();
                    this.shown = true;
                } else {
                    // $(this.textelements[0]).show();
                    // console.log(" ~ file: main.js ~ line 38 ~ LinkContainer ~ linkcontainers.forEach ~ textelements", $(this.textelements[0]));
                    this.textelements.forEach((textelement) => {
                        textelement.style.display = state;
                        textelement.closest('.section').style.display = state;
                        //     // t1.fromTo(textelement, 0.1, {
                        //     //     opacity: "0" }, {
                        //     //     opacity: "1"
                        //     // });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

linkcontainerobjects = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('link-container'));

// console.log(linkcontainerobjects);

linkcontainers = [];

linkcontainerobjects.forEach((container) => {
    console.log(container.dataset.alias);
    let colours = container.getElementsByClassName('colour');
    linkcontainers.push(
        new LinkContainer(
            container.dataset.alias,
            container.getElementsByClassName('link')[0],
            [colours[0], colours[1], colours[2], colours[3]],
            document.getElementsByClassName(container.dataset.alias)
        )
    );
});



// const tl = new TimelineMax();
const speed = 0.05;
const width = '40%'
console.log(linkcontainers);
linkcontainers.forEach((container) => {
    container.link.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
        // if (!container.animating) {
        //     container.animating = true;
        //     container.colours.forEach((colour) => {
        //         tl.fromTo(colour, speed, {
        //             width: "0%"
        //         }, {
        //             width: width,
        //         });
        //     });
        // } container.animating = false;
        container.toggletextelements('block');
    });

    container.link.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) => {
        // if (!container.animating) {
        //     container.animating = true;
        //     container.colours.forEach((colour) => {
        //         tl.fromTo(colour, speed, {
        //             width: width
        //         }, {
        //             width: "0%"
        //         });
        //     });
        // } container.animating = false;
        container.toggletextelements('none');
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap');

body {
    background-color: rgb(15, 15, 15);
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    /* overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden; */
    grid-template: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.links {
    margin: 10% 0 0 5%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
    width: 40%;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.link {
    color: white;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 2;
}

.colour {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 75px;
    transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(-1px);
    z-index: 1;
}

.one {
    background-color: #00DDFF;
}

.two {
    background-color: #00FFAE;
}

.three {
    background-color: #7bff00;
}

.four {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #00e1ff, #D0FF00);
    /* width: 100%; */
}

.section {
    height: 100%;
    grid-column: 2 / 2;
    display: none;
    transform:
            translateX(-3em)
            translateY(-4.5em);
}

.section > div {
    display: none;
}

.section svg {
    position: absolute;
    display: inherit;
    transform:
            scale(120%)
            rotate(-90deg)
            translateX(-1em)
            translateY(-37em);
}

.filler {
    background-color: #0a97ff;
    position: absolute;
    display: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 152.4%;
    transform:
            translateX(5em);
}

.section p {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    display: inherit;
    width: 20em;
    text-align: right;
    transform:
            translateX(2em)
            translateY(15em);
}

.section h1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    display: inherit;
    font-size: 5em;
    width: 29%;
    text-align: right;
    transform:
            translateX(4em)
            translateY(3em);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="links">
    <div class="link-container" data-alias="home" id="home">
        <div class="colour one"></div>
        <div class="colour two"></div>
        <div class="colour three"></div>
        <div class="colour four"></div>
        <a class="link" href="#">home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container" data-alias="projects">
        <div class="colour one"></div>
        <div class="colour two"></div>
        <div class="colour three"></div>
        <div class="colour four"></div>
        <a class="link" href="#">projects</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container" data-alias="about">
        <div class="colour one"></div>
        <div class="colour two"></div>
        <div class="colour three"></div>
        <div class="colour four"></div>
        <a class="link" href="#">about</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container" data-alias="training">
        <div class="colour one"></div>
        <div class="colour two"></div>
        <div class="colour three"></div>
        <div class="colour four"></div>
        <a class="link" href="#">training</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container" data-alias="experiments">
        <div class="colour one"></div>
        <div class="colour two"></div>
        <div class="colour three"></div>
        <div class="colour four"></div>
        <a class="link" href="#">experiments</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container" data-alias="contact">
        <div class="colour one"></div>
        <div class="colour two"></div>
        <div class="colour three"></div>
        <div class="colour four"></div>
        <a class="link" href="#">contact</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="section">
    <div class="home">
        <svg id="visual" class="content home"
             viewBox="0 0 900 600" width="900" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><path d="" fill="#0a97ff"></path></svg>
        <div class="filler home"></div>
        <h1 class="content projects home">
            Home
        </h1>
        <p class="content home">
            Pariatur proident commodo adipisicing cillum quis. Officia do do ipsum laborum commodo et nulla consequat
            culpa elit aute. Elit sit eiusmod qui amet amet fugiat est. Consectetur deserunt incididunt excepteur labore
            ullamco ut irure dolor. Ipsum laborum irure fugiat aute exercitation incididunt nostrud dolor proident
            laborum culpa. Deserunt Lorem ex duis ex do officia cupidatat id duis sit. Eu dolor non ad est dolore.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="projects">
        <svg class="content projects" id="visual" viewBox="0 0 900 600" width="900" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><path d="" fill="#0a97ff"></path></svg>
        <h1 class="content projects">
            Projects
        </h1>
        <p class="content projects">
            Pariatur proident commodo adipisicing cillum quis. Officia do do ipsum laborum commodo et nulla consequat
            culpa elit aute. Elit sit eiusmod qui amet amet fugiat est. Consectetur deserunt incididunt excepteur labore
            ullamco ut irure dolor. Ipsum laborum irure fugiat aute exercitation incididunt nostrud dolor proident
            laborum culpa. Deserunt Lorem ex duis ex do officia cupidatat id duis sit. Eu dolor non ad est dolore.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="about">
        <svg class="content about" id="outer" viewBox="0 0 1000 800" width="1000" height="900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="800" fill="#0f0f0f"></rect>
            <g transform="translate(534.7368600969783 383.1406775770206)">
                <path
                        d=""
                        fill="#00fff0"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg class="content projects" id="visual" viewBox="0 0 900 600" width="900" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><path d="" fill="#0a97ff"></path></svg>
        <h1 class="content about">
            About
        </h1>
        <p class="content about">
            Pariatur proident commodo adipisicing cillum quis. Officia do do ipsum laborum commodo et nulla consequat
            culpa elit aute. Elit sit eiusmod qui amet amet fugiat est. Consectetur deserunt incididunt excepteur labore
            ullamco ut irure dolor. Ipsum laborum irure fugiat aute exercitation incididunt nostrud dolor proident
            laborum culpa. Deserunt Lorem ex duis ex do officia cupidatat id duis sit. Eu dolor non ad est dolore.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="training">
        <svg class="content training" id="visual" viewBox="0 0 900 600" width="900" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><path d="" fill="#0a97ff"></path></svg>
        <h1 class="content training">
            Lorem
        </h1>
        <p class="content training">
            Pariatur proident commodo adipisicing cillum quis. Officia do do ipsum laborum commodo et nulla consequat
            culpa elit aute. Elit sit eiusmod qui amet amet fugiat est. Consectetur deserunt incididunt excepteur labore
            ullamco ut irure dolor. Ipsum laborum irure fugiat aute exercitation incididunt nostrud dolor proident
            laborum culpa. Deserunt Lorem ex duis ex do officia cupidatat id duis sit. Eu dolor non ad est dolore.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="experiments">
        <svg class="content experiments" id="visual" viewBox="0 0 900 600" width="900" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><path d="" fill="#0a97ff"></path></svg>
        <h1 class="content experimentsw">
            Lorem
        </h1>
        <p class="content experiments">
            Pariatur proident commodo adipisicing cillum quis. Officia do do ipsum laborum commodo et nulla consequat
            culpa elit aute. Elit sit eiusmod qui amet amet fugiat est. Consectetur deserunt incididunt excepteur labore
            ullamco ut irure dolor. Ipsum laborum irure fugiat aute exercitation incididunt nostrud dolor proident
            laborum culpa. Deserunt Lorem ex duis ex do officia cupidatat id duis sit. Eu dolor non ad est dolore.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        <svg class="content contact" id="visual" viewBox="0 0 900 600" width="900" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><path d="" fill="#0a97ff"></path></svg>
        <h1 class="content contact">
            Lorem
        </h1>
        <p class="content contact">
            Pariatur proident commodo adipisicing cillum quis. Officia do do ipsum laborum commodo et nulla consequat
            culpa elit aute. Elit sit eiusmod qui amet amet fugiat est. Consectetur deserunt incididunt excepteur labore
            ullamco ut irure dolor. Ipsum laborum irure fugiat aute exercitation incididunt nostrud dolor proident
            laborum culpa. Deserunt Lorem ex duis ex do officia cupidatat id duis sit. Eu dolor non ad est dolore.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TimelineMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/kute.js@2.1.2/dist/kute.min.js
    "></script>
<script src="codes.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

That does not show and hide contents smoothly. Maybe because I disabled your animations or maybe you need extra styles. But that solves the main problem (applying changing styles in js).

Comment: Hey! thankyou so much for your answer, yeah I didn't change it to the state as i was just debugging, It's working now! I'm not really sure why though, what does the ```.closest()``` method do that is different? Just so i can prevent this error later. Anyway, thankyou so much for your answer, i appreciate it a whole lot

Comment: @CoopCodes The ```.closest()``` is just a js method that helps you to select the ```.section``` class as the parent of each ```div```. I used it to **show** and **hide** both parent and child simultaneously. You can read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help. Just one more question, sorry, why can't i just pass in a HTMLElement as a parameter into a JS function? And edit its properties like that?

Comment: @CoopCodes JS functions are a lot. Which function did you mean? For example [getElementsByTagName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp) method accepts HTML elements as a parameter. If you have any special question, I suggest ask it separately to get better answers.